# How to query distribution with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join, recursive-query

I am looking for methods to query frequency distributions with MySQL. I have a table with a column documenting dates and another event occurrence. The ideal output is a table with values of event count in ascending order and their corresponding frequency.

Table

```
--------------------
|dates | event_count|
---------------------
|03/02 |  4         |
|03/03 |  3         |
|03/04 |  5         |
|03/05 |  2         |
|03/06 |  2         |
|03/06 |  5         |
---------------------
```

Resulting Table

```
    ------------------------
    |event_count | frequency|
    ------------------------
    |0           |0         |
    |1           |0         |
    |2           |2         |
    |3           |1         |
    |4           |1         |
    |5           |2         |
    -------------------------
```

Any advice is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select event_count, count(*) frequency
from mytable 
group by event_count
```

On the other hand, if you want rows for all possible `event_count`, even if they do not appear in the table, then it is a bit different. One method uses a recursive query to generate the values, and then brings the table with a `left join`:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 0 event_count, max(event_count) max_event_count from mytable
    union all
    select event_count + 1 from cte where event_count < max_event_count
)
select c.event_count, count(t.event_count) frequency
from cte c
left join mytable t on t.event_count = c.event_count
group by c.event_count
```

Recursive queries are available in MySQL 8.0 only.